# terminate oci instance using instance_action

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to find the best way to terminate an oci instance using the oci python library. I know that I can stop an instance with

```
base_compute.instance_action(instance_id, 'STOP')
```

However, I do not see a `TERMINATE` action in their documentation:https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/tools/oci-cli/2.21.5/oci_cli_docs/cmdref/compute/instance/action.html for the method. Any help with this would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer this document, it has the Oracle CLI command to [terminate the instance](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/tools/oci-cli/2.21.5/oci_cli_docs/cmdref/compute/instance/terminate.html).

Command: `oci compute instance terminate [OPTIONS]`

Comment: Yep I went with that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can terminate an instance by calling either [`compute_client.terminate_instance`](https://github.com/oracle/oci-python-sdk/blob/master/src/oci/core/compute_client.py#L6923) or [`compute_client_composite_operations.terminate_instance_and_wait_for_state`](https://github.com/oracle/oci-python-sdk/blob/master/src/oci/core/compute_client_composite_operations.py#L1114) if you want your code wait for it to finish.

Here's [an example from the Python SDK](https://github.com/oracle/oci-python-sdk/blob/master/examples/launch_instance_example.py#L403-L411):

```py
def terminate_instance(compute_client_composite_operations, instance):
    print('Terminating Instance: {}'.format(instance.id))
    compute_client_composite_operations.terminate_instance_and_wait_for_state(
        instance.id,
        wait_for_states=[oci.core.models.Instance.LIFECYCLE_STATE_TERMINATED]
    )

    print('Terminated Instance: {}'.format(instance.id))
    print()
```